# Can I use United in-flight entertainment on Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, internet

Is it in anyway possible to make my device *look* like an Android/Windows/Mac device to utilize the inflight entertainment services on the flight wifi? It seems that only the above devices are supported. I guess I can spoof a MAC address from a old iPhone but that would not solve the problem in my mind.

Just to clarify, I'm able to connect to the WiFi network during the flight but I can't use the inflight entertainment services that you are supposed to be able to access through that service.

See
https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/inflight/entertainment/personal-device-entertainment.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure how a wifi network can only support certain OS's. What's the wifi protocol and security protocol? If you try to connect, what happens?

Comment: The WiFi connects to the plane wifi, but the 'inflight' entertainment doesn't seem to function on Ubuntu. I eventually saw this https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/inflight/entertainment/personal-device-entertainment.aspx (see supported devices) and figured that was the problem.

Comment: It is probably a browser issue if the content is delivered through a browser. If you aren't using google chrome I would try that.

Comment: United says that is doesn't support chrome currently, although I'll try it. I use Firefox and the guy sitting next to me on the flight used a win10 laptop with Firefox and he seemed to be fine.

Comment: @Padawan Ah, so it's the inflight entertainment system that doesn't work. Well, if Linux is not supported, then it's probably just not possible, although you could look into a hack like installing Flash on Wine (and spoofing a Windows browser user agent if necessary), or installing the Android app in Chrome using ARChon. FYI, from the link it looks like the entertainment system uses NPAPI, which Chrome has removed and Firefox will soon remove.